# Subresource Integrity in angularJS App which uses Require JS

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, require, subresource-integrity

I have an angular application with below index.html file

Consider in my index.html page I have the following code for SRI (SubResource Integrity)

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
      content="script-src 'self' scripts/alert.js 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' 'sha256-qznLcsROx4GACP2dm0UCKCzCG+HiZ1guq6ZZDob/Tng='">

<script src="scripts/alert.js"
        integrity="sha256-qznLcsROx4GACP2dm0UCKCzCG+HiZ1guq6ZZDob/Tng="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
</html>
```

In case, if I am using require JS, then I have to move the script inclusion of 'alert.js' to 'main.js' file as below

```html
require.config({


    // alias libraries paths
    paths: {
            'jquery': '/scripts/alert'
            },
    // kick start application
    deps: ['../app/require.bootstrap']
 })
```

Can someone help me how to include the integrity attribute to the main.js file while referring the alert.js script in the paths.

Answer (score 12):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to use Sub Resource Integrity for scripts referenced via require js. Note, that in order to do this you need RequireJS version 2.1.19 or later (see http://requirejs.org/docs/download.html).

For a working example (referencing jQuery), see this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/kzqLjUThJRtoEruCCtMt?p=preview. Hopefully you should be able to copy this method to your project.

My example uses integrity/crossorigin attributes for:

- RequireJS itself (through the `index.html` file)
- jQuery (via the config file `main.js` and the interesting thing for you)

This is built on the RequireJS hook `onNodeCreated` and code like

```
onNodeCreated: function(node, config, module, path) {
    node.setAttribute('integrity', integrityForModule);
    node.setAttribute('crossorigin', 'anonymous');
}
```

Please note that this example does NOT use SRI for the config file `main.js` file. In order to accomplish that, either

- include the RequireJS config inline in the `index.html` page
- ...or reference `main.js` (the config file) through an extra script tag (with integrity/crossover), and not via the `data-main` attribute