# RequireJS & Subresource Integrity (SRI)

Tags: requirejs, subresource-integrity

Does anybody know how to set up Subresource Integrity (SRI) attributes for the JS URLs that are located in the 'paths' area of the config file in RequireJS?

RequireJS say on their website that it supports SRI, but I can't find any information out there on how to implement it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subresource Integrity in angularJS App which uses Require JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34348536/subresource-integrity-in-angularjs-app-which-uses-require-js)

Comment: I'm looking for some example too, for now without success.

Comment: Really usable answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34348536/subresource-integrity-in-angularjs-app-which-uses-require-js?lq=1#answer-37065379)