# Is there a way to specify script integrity of modules?

Tags: javascript, html, integrity

I use subresource integrity for normal scripts on my page but currently not for JavaScript modules.

I assume that specifying the integrity of a module included with the script tag works like the following [What are the integrity and crossorigin attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32039568/what-are-the-integrity-and-crossorigin-attributes), just with the additional `type="module"`. Is this correct?

How do I specify the integrity of modules included in other modules (e.g. with `import * as blah from "blah.js";`)?

Is there a way to specify the integrity of these imports? Is it possible to specify them in all in one place in the HTML (for example in module preloads) so if a module deep down changes, not all intergrities of the modules using them change as well?

Comment: Note that [there is actually a way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63029759/3702797), in Blink browsers only for now.

Comment: @Kaiido Yeah, I'm using that for now. Sadly only blink browsers support it at the moment...

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK "integrity" attribute is used to "verify" that the content on the other server still is the same (same SHA-sum, not manipulated).

So you would use this to include Ressources hosted on third-party-server like CDN`s

If the files you import * as blah are coming from your local directory, there is probably no check for manipulation required, if you wanted to check the integrity you could just imprt them with a script tag or look at the link below:

[Subresource integrity for es6 import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52636690/subresource-integrity-for-es6-import)

at the end it´s just comparing the sha-sum of the file, you could do it on your own

In this link is basically everything said about it
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Subresource_Integrity